# ModelMapper produces exception while converting Entity to DTO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, modelmapper

I am trying to convert Entities to DTOs, which are used in a Rest service.

My Entity is the below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column(name = "LOGIN")
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "ENABLED")
    private Boolean enabled;
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "DATE_FORMAT")
    private String dateFormat;
    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    @Column(name = "LAST_ACCESS_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime lastAccessDate;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

And the relevant DTO:

```
public class UserDto extends AbstractDto {

    private String login;
    private String password;
    private Boolean enabled;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String dateFormat;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    private LocalDateTime lastAccessDate;
    private List<RoleDto> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am using ModelMapper in order to convert my entities to DTOs and vice versa. However, when I send a request to the Rest API, I get the below error:

```
Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter@67aa8104 failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag to java.util.List.

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwMappingExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:380) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:81) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:573) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:406) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at eu.voiceweb.business.services.MapperService.getMappedObject(MapperService.java:49) ~[Reporting-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at eu.voiceweb.business.services.MapperService.getDto(MapperService.java:31) ~[Reporting-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at eu.voiceweb.business.services.UserService.getUserByLogin(UserService.java:63) ~[Reporting-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at eu.voiceweb.restapi.UserController.getUserByUsername(UserController.java:45) ~[dialogManager-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45) [tomee-catalina-8.0.0-M2.jar:8.0.0-M2]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97) [tomee-catalina-8.0.0-M2.jar:8.0.0-M2]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: eu.voiceweb.persistence.entities.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.util.Iterables.getLength(Iterables.java:50) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter.convert(MergingCollectionConverter.java:44) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter.convert(MergingCollectionConverter.java:31) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:303) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:110) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:242) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:188) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:152) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:115) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:72) ~[modelmapper-2.3.3.jar:na]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
2019-05-15 13:25:26,065 ERROR [http-nio-18000-exec-9] [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221] An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45) [tomee-catalina-8.0.0-M2.jar:8.0.0-M2]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97) [tomee-catalina-8.0.0-M2.jar:8.0.0-M2]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at eu.voiceweb.services.UserService.getUserFromResponse(UserService.java:104) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.voiceweb.services.UserService.getUserByUsername(UserService.java:78) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.voiceweb.services.UserService.loadUserByUsername(UserService.java:115) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Initially, the fetch type in the entity was LAZY, I had changed it to EAGER and it work. But I have read that this is bad for the project's performance. I have tried the OpenSessionInViewFilter in the web app initializer class with no result.Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I think the outermost level of your JSON dont begins with an Object or Array literal.
Can you post your json here?

Comment: The problem is that no JSON is produced since there is an error in the backend. When the Controller uses a service to retrieve a list of Users, I get this exception due the @ManyToMany relationship between Users and Roles. I just want to figure out how can I convert my entity to a DTO with all the fields (including the list of roles)

Comment: if in most requests to Users you need to use Roles list then use EAGER FetchType, also to improve performance you can add  Cacheable and  Cache annotations to Role class in this way this entity will loaded from cache instead of data base

Answer (score 3):

The error is

> Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role:
>   eu.voiceweb.persistence.entities.User.roles, could not initialize
>   proxy - no Session

So that means that the roles list is not initialized when the object is serialized.

You have to make sure that the initalization happens where you read the data.

For example with a JOIN FETCH in your query, an EntityGraph or by simply accessing the collection in the data access layer.